# Oracle: How to add 6 months to current date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

In SQL Server I can do this to add 6 months to the current date:

```
DateAdd(Month, 6, CURRENT_DATE)
```

What is the equivalent in Oracle?

Comment: It's still SQL, just another dialect. :)

Answer (score 45):

The equivalent is:

```
ADD_MONTHS( CURRENT_DATE, 6 )
```