# SQL Querying a Database Using The Current Date and Date associated with an Attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am trying to query a from scratch database I created. For each job posting in my database, I store the date of which it was posted in the 'date' datatype, which is in the format of "DD-MON-YY". I want to know which job postings haven't been filled after one month after its posted date.

So far I can query my database and find which jobs haven't been filled, due to a particular attribute being null in my table. But I don't know how to add the condition that it has been at least one month.

```
SELECT JOBID
FROM JOB
WHERE HIRED IS NULL;
```

For reference I have created this database in Oracle, and am using SQL developer.

Comment: "which is in the format of "DD-MON-YY"" No, it is not; a `DATE` is a binary data type and has no format. The user interface you are using may choose to *display* the `DATE` in that format but the database does not *store* it in the format (or any format) as it uses 7 bytes for century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second (and always has those components even if the UI doesn't show some of them).

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the: `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for some sample data that demonstrates the problem; and your expected output for that sample data. You do not tell us which column stores the date nor whether you want to compare it to the current date or another column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114021/oracle-how-to-add-6-months-to-current-date

Comment: How do you define "one month after" a specific date? This is ambiguous at month ends. For example: the date is April 30. When is "one month after" - on May 30, or on May 31? Different such functions in Oracle database don't even agree with each other on this topic. So, please clarify. Or does "any reasonable answer" work for you?

Comment: Any reasonable answer works, I was looking for a more general answer. I don't understand how I can add a condition that is the date I've posted plus one month. I guess to rephrase, how would I make that condition, would I add one month to the date stored and the compare it with today's date? I guess I don't understand the logic.

Comment: Please check [Datetime functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-5652DBC2-41C7-4F07-BEDD-DAF620E35F3C) and [Datetime/Interval Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705)

Answer (score 0):

> I guess to rephrase, how would I make that condition, would I add one month to the date stored and the compare it with today's date?

Compare your date column to the current date with `-1` months added to it:

```sql
SELECT JOBID
FROM   JOB
WHERE  HIRED IS NULL
AND    date_column <= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1);
```